# Fragment with bounded services in android

Tags: android, service

I have an `Activity` that contains 3 `Fragments` . and i have a bounded `Service`.

is it true that each call of

```
getActivity(). bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

inside each Fragment will result in 3 clients binds to the bounded `Service` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will give you three client for bounded service.

What you could do to make sure you have only one client service is

override bindService method as shown below. Note: with this you have only one bounded service for the activity.

```
private IBinder binder;
private ComponentName name;
private ArrayList<ServiceConnection> conns = new ArrayList<ServiceConnection>();
@Override
    public boolean bindService(Intent service, final ServiceConnection conn, int flags)    {
conns.add(conn);
        if(binder != null)
            conn.onServiceConnected(name, binder);
        return super.bindService(service, new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
for(ServiceConnection con : conns)
con.onServiceDisconnected(arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder arg1) {
                name = arg0;
                binder = arg1;
                conn.onServiceConnected(arg0, arg1);
            }
        }, flags);
    }
```